# PyQt grouping graphicsScene objects into one object

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

**Background:** I am attempting to make a griding tool using python and pyqt. Specifically I want to use the graphicsView/graphicsScene combination to allow the user to place and edit sections of grid. In this context, the grid is simply a collection of perpendicular lines.

Something Like:
[image]

**Question:** How do I group a collection of lines together into a single object so that the collection of lines acts as a single object (i.e. context menu, dragging, etc.)

**Current Code:**(only the graphics classes)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class graphicsView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(graphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        super(graphicsView, self).wheelEvent(event)
        factor = 1.2
        if event.delta()<0:
            factor = 1.0/factor
        self.scale(factor,factor)

class graphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(graphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.meshPen=QtGui.QPen(QtCOre.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
    def newGrid(self, xmax,ymax,xcells,ycells,xmin=0,ymin=0):
        for i in range(xcells+1):
            x=i*(xmax-xmin)/xcells-abs(xmin)
            self.addLine(x,ymin,x,ymax,self.meshPen)
        for j in range(ycells+1):
            y=j*(ymax-ymin)/ycells-abs(ymin)
            self.addLine(xmin,y,xmax,y,self.meshPen)
```

**System:**
Python 2.7.2, PyQt4 4.9.5-2, windows 7

---

**Possible Solutions:**(my random thoughts)

1. Implement an invisible rectangle ontop of the grid to handle interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it is [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsitemgroup.html):

```
def newGrid(...):
     group = QtGui.QGraphicsItemGroup(scene=self)
     group.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable) #let't test how it works

     for i in range(xccells + 1):
         ...
         group.addToGroup(self.addLine(x,ymin,x,ymax,self.meshPen))
     ...
```

Comment: Nice. I did not realize that there was a QGraphicsItemGroup. I will have to try it out.